# Create readme.md files including images in them dynamically

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp, github-api, readme

i am working an an application in angularJs that displays `readme.md` files from github and also generated readme files dynamically what api should i use to access readme.md from GitHub and also create a readme file that has images in it.

Comment: What efforts have you made yet other than asking this question to do this task?

Comment: i am able to access the repositories from github using json callback but how can i access the readme.md files?

Comment: have you checked [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types)? show me your angular code you are working on for getting the readme.md file.